# php cURL to only return body without img tags

Tags: php, image, curl

I just want to return the `body`  and no IMG tags so it would return faster.  Can this be achieved with cURL?

```
 $curl_handle=curl_init();

$fullurl = "http://www.basequipment.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);

$returned = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($returned);
```

Comment: This code is not fetching any images.

Comment: What you get is raw html of the homepage, no style, javascript, images etc will be included. It is up to the client processing the raw html to get those from the specified URIs

Comment: ... if you want to remove any img tags, use HTML/DOM parser and delete them from the DOM

Comment: this is what i meant.  I want to not include anything in the header tag and any img tags, i will update question.

Comment: @ToddN but that won't make anything load faster, at least not in this code. What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Well if I wanted to scrap say 50 pages at a time I dont want to run into any timeout issues or memory issues was my concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cURL only fetches the given URL and that is the pure HTML page URL. On the page there are several images with different URL-s those won't be fetched except you create another cURL connection.